# Translate extbase Extension Records

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

Soon I will create an extension to save data and images and display them with 2 different plugins on the frontend. The Site is multilingual (one-tree) and so it must be possible for editors to translate this records to their language.

I tried to google how to do this and found different information, some say its not possible. But I guess most of them are outdated.

So my question is, what is needed so that records are translateable?

The Typo3 Version will be 7.6

Answer (score 1):

Extbase records are translateable in the backend if they

- Have the needed fields in the database (`sys_language_uid`, `l10n_parent`, `l10n_diffsource`, `t3_origuid`)
- Have the according TCA configuration

Just kickstart a sample extension with the extension_builder. All records should have the fields and TCA needed for translation.

Comment: Sounds good thx. I will come back to this question when I am at this point and accept your answer or write another comment